# What is the in built function or super global to get sql database server hostname using php?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, hostname

I wanted to connect php file to be connected with a sql server database. I got the error message saying connection string failed and check database instance name or hostname.

```
$serverName = "00.000.000.000:1234"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( 
         "Database"=>"rmrwordpress","UID"=>"rmrdbadmin", "PWD"=>"*****"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Hosting providing team is not helping and I had spent 11days asking for this. I decided to use **a php function which can get hostname of database server and instance of SQL server 2012 or 2008**. So that I can use that for my database connection.

1. I had used servername, computer name and IP in the place of $servername one after the other but didn't worked.

So please share your knowledge about an in-built function or super global which can return the hostname which can be similar to

> echo gethostname();

OR

> php_uname('n');

**What is the in built function or super global to get sql database server hostname using php?**

Comment: There isn't a function for this in PHP. Have you tried 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I used 127.0.01 with or without port number but it didn't worked. So I have to be dependent on the hosting provider no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of hosting companies don't have the sql server on the same host as the web-servers. getting the name of the host that the php script is running on may not help you.

You can try looking at the $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] information in the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array. But that would be the same as just using 'localhost' for your server address.

But php has no way of guessing where an SQL server might reside, because it could be anywhere on the internet/LAN/localhost

Comment: You may be correct but I am not sure Loopo because the final array of error message says, 

> Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: I printed $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] but it doesn't echo anything. Also I EXPERIMENTED using the result of $_SERVER[LOCAL_ADDR], $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] and $_SERVER[REMOTE_HOST] but no positive result. I appreciate you effort even though I couldn't able to accept your answer. Also ScallioXTX can you justify that there are no function to get db hostname and instance using php?

Comment: I have found that with most hosting providers there is a section in the control panel or FAQ that tells you were your database server is, possibly with the name of the database that you are allowed to use.

Comment: I can't justify it (as there is no source talking about stuff that isn't in PHP), but I've never seen any functions like you ask, and I'm sure they're not in PHP. Why would PHP know where your database is? That's your job -or indeed the hoster's job- to know, not PHP's job. It's your job to tell PHP where the database is, not the other way around. Moreover, there could be multiple servers, how would PHP know which one to pick? It just doesn't make sense that any language would have functions for it. How do you figure it should?